# Apache CXF Jaxrs Webclient, GET request JSON Payload

Tags: json, jax-rs, webclient, unmarshalling

#### According to the API documentation, the request should be structured as follows:

```
{
  "productType": "string"
}
```

*which is I believe,*

```
"{\"productType\": \"string\"}"
```

#### I'm getting the same error since last 2 weeks.

> com.ericsson.suf.csufc.license.NeLSLicenseManager getRequest reason:The request content was malformed:
> Cannot unmarshal JSON as GetLicense

#### Can anyone solve the above problem?

#### I've tried writing

```
{
public WebClient buildgetWebClient() {
    List<Object> providers = new ArrayList<Object>();
    providers.add(new JacksonJsonProvider());
    WebClient client = null;
    try {
        client = WebClient.create(get_url, providers);
        if("https".equals(protocol)) {
            try {
                addX509TrustManager(client);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                LogController.logInfoMessage("Exception :"+Utility.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }
        client = client.accept("application/json").type("application/json");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        LogController.logSevereMessage("Exception :"+Utility.getStackTrace(e));
    }
    return client;
}`

`public boolean sendgetrequest() 
{
        
    WebClient client = null;
    int intRetryAfter = adplm_default_license_req_period;
    boolean getflag = true;

    try
    {
        reason = "";
        LogController.logInfoMessage("Sending NeLS GET request");
        LogController.logInfoMessage("GET_URL : "+get_url);
        client = buildgetWebClient();
        Map<String, String> request = new HashMap<String, String>();
        request.put("productType", "Charging");
        
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);
        
        Response response = client.invoke(HttpMethod.GET, request);
        getrestStatus =  response.getStatus();
        
        
        NeLSLicenseResponseGET nelsresponse = response.readEntity(NeLSLicenseResponseGET.class);
        NeLSOperationalMode operationMode =  nelsresponse.getOperationalStatusInfo().getOperationalMode();
    }
}`
```